# Dynatrace Integration with JMeter using JMeterConvert.sh

Tags: jmeter, dynatrace, apm

I'm trying to convert my JMeter script into dynatrace aware one. 
Dynatrace has published a tool which supposed to do it automatically.

Link to the source: 
https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DL/JMeter+Integration

```
./JMeterConvert.sh -source old.jmx -target new.jmx
```

I'm wondering if there is anyone there who has tried to do it.
After running above in terminal i end up with new script looking exactly the same - dynatrace headers are not being applied. 
I would be grateful to find someone who has attempted it before.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post this question on our Dynatrace Discussion Form? http://answers.dynatrace.com. Or post this as a comment on the download page. The author of that conversion tool will then see your comment and can reply.

Andi

Comment: I'm not registered user on dynatrace. Registration takes apparently 2 working days. Additionally this product is listed as not supported. I hope registration process won't take much longer.

Comment: You just sign up for the free trial - http://www.dynatrace.com/en/products/dynatrace-personal-license.html - and you automatically get an account. if you are a customer and you use your corporate email you will also automatically get an account -> key here is that you use your corporate email so that we can verify it with our backend system

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an up to date and simple Apache JMeter integration with Dynatrace, then have a look at the Monitoring Plugin for JMeter provided by UbikLoadPack:

- https://ubikloadpack.com/tryout.php (select **Monitoring**)

This plugin allows you to integrate with:

- [Dynatrace AppMon](https://www.dynatrace.com/platform/oneagent/) to record Dynatrace sessions and tag Web Requests
- [Dynatrace One Agent](https://www.dynatrace.com/platform/oneagent/) to be able to correlate response times, other monitoring graphs and Artificial Intelligence for analysis

Disclaimer : We are providers of this solution