# JMeterConvert:convert my jmeter script to dynaTrace header

Tags: jmeter, converters, dynatrace

I am trying convert my jmeter script to dynaTrace header, using JMeterConvert. As installing JMeterConvert was not given clearly in the site I was referring I feel like I am lost. Can anyone kindly help me with that.

I have downloaded JMeterScriptConverter which has three files:

1. JMeterConvert
2. JMeterConvert.sh
3. scriptconverter

Answer (score 1):

The script you are mentioning is an old unmaintained converter.

To integrate JMeter with Dynatrace you would need to follow:

- https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT63/Integration+with+Web+Load+Testing+and+Monitoring+Tools#

Use a HeaderManager that you put under Thread Group, thanks to JMeter scoping rules it will apply to all requests.

Then in this HeaderManager add a Header :

> X-Dynatrace

That will contain:

> NA=${[__samplerName()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__samplerName)};SN=;TE=;SI=WLT;VU=-${[__threadNum()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)}

Where:

ThreadGroupName : name of your thread group

Note that If you're looking for an up to date and simple Apache JMeter integration with Dynatrace, then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822814/460802